# material UI styled() doesn't show up

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

In my index.jsx file, I tried to use the MUI styled() utility, but the style isn't applied to `<MyComponent>Styled div</MyComponent>`. Why?

```
    import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
    import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
    import Card from '@mui/material/Card'
    import CardActions from '@mui/material/CardActions'
    import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent'
    import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia'
    import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
    import { styled } from '@mui/system';
    import Head from 'next/head'
    import Image from 'next/image'
   
    
    
    const MyComponent = styled('div')({
      color: 'darkslategray',
      backgroundColor: 'aliceblue',
      padding: 8,
      borderRadius: 4,
    });

    
    export const index = () => {
    
      return (
        <>
          <Head>
            ...
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            <link
              rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&family=Mukta:wght@500;600&display=swap"
            />
          </Head>
    
          <MyComponent>Styled div</MyComponent>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use it like this?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

Comment: when I put "const classes = useStyles();" inside the export function I get this error: "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. "

Comment: This error is perfectly normal. because you need to write this hook in related component. You don't have to write outside.

Comment: To make sure I understand, are you saying I should write "const useStyles = makeStyles" in the file of another component instead in the same file?